# Converting multiple column into one while summing their values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df` which has 132 columns. Now I want to create  a new data frame `df2` which has only 11 columns where 1st column of `df2` will have values that is sum of the values of 1 to 12 columns from `df` ; 2nd column of `df2` will have values  that is sum of the values of 13 to 24 columns from `df` and so on. For instance.

```
>df
A B C D E F G H I J K L 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
...
```

```
A...
12
14
..
```

Here in df2 , the first column has the value that is sum of first 12 columns of `df`

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby`:

```
#sample data
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(2*132).reshape(2, -1))

df2 = df.groupby(np.arange(df.shape[1])//12, axis=1).sum()
```

Output:

```
     0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9     10
0    66   210   354   498   642   786   930  1074  1218  1362  1506
1  1650  1794  1938  2082  2226  2370  2514  2658  2802  2946  3090
```